# How to tell if wifi is connected and to which wifi network. Ubuntu MATE 17.04

Tags: networking, wireless

How can I tell whether wifi is connected, and if it is, to which network.

Toshiba Satellite L455-S5975, Celeron 2.2Ghz, 2GB RAM.  Ubuntu MATE 17.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the *Control Center* (e. g. through the application dash, the settings menu of your desktop environment) and from there open the network settings. It will display a list of known network connections (wired, wireless and virtual). If you select individual network connections from the list you will see their state in the status pane next to the list. For wireless networks it will include the SSID of the access point if associated to one.

Comment: Hi David,  thank you for replying to my question.  Along the same line as your answer, do you, (or anyone) know how to get the pull down menu under the network icon to slow down or stop.  It's changing so fast that I can't select the network I want.  After many tries, i get the network, I type in the password as directed, the computer seems to be trying to log on, the wifi icon very active, after a while it gives up and the wifi icon goes still and empty.  A message appears, Disconnected.  In the Network Connections box under last used it says- never.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Nocronym: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.

Comment: I am going to post a new question relating to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

First run

```
iwconfig
```

To see the name of your wifi device (e.g. `wlps10`)

then run

```
iwconfig yourdevice
```

so my command is

```
iwconfig wlps10
```

Comment: Thank you chazecka.  I have to shut down for the day.  I will run your commands tomorrow and post results...

Comment: Hi chazecka,  Ran iwconfig twice as suggested.  Here is the output:  wlx701a0472b412  IEEE 802.11  ESSID: off/any  Mode: Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated  Tx-Power=20 dBm  Retry short llimit:7  RTS thr:off  Power management:off.   Any suggestions?  I don't understand most of that.

Comment: Only what bothers you is the ESSID: line .. but your ESSID is kinda broken, what router are you connected to? Is the router properly set? (there should be like ESSID: Johny's router)

Comment: Thanks chazecka.  This is a public net, so I don't have access to the router.  But, other computers connect to this wifi net no problem.

Comment: You can consider installing network-manager (if you dont have one). sudo apt-get install network-manager

Comment: I am going to post a new question relating to my problem.